# React js Convert a srt/txt file to docx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx, txt, srt

I have a `srt/txt` file I have to make sure to convert it to a `docx` file.

I tried to simply rename it to `docx`, but it is considered an invalid document format.

So I'm wondering how do I get it to be considered valid?

Do I need to change any attributes in the file?

Comment: They're are two different formats so you have to find a way to actually convert between them. There are lots of solutions out there - APIs, Pandoc (if you can use NodeJS). But no - you can't just change the extension, or the file attributes.

Comment: @Andy: By Apis do you mean an external service?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Comment: Since SRT files are mostly text files, a document conversion toolkit that supports MS Office formats can be used to convert the text into DOCX. For example, the LEADTOOLS toolkit is able to do this using the [DocumentConverter](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) class (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor). The document conversion is also available as a [Cloud Service](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/cloud-services/convert.html).